# How to convert FEMA flood map (FEMA NFHL v3.2 kmz) to GeoJSON

Tags: python, geojson, web-service, kmz

TLDR: Using Python, how can I convert a kmz file to GeoJSON? It appears that the kmz file makes web service calls.

Details:

I downloaded the `FEMA_NFHL_v3.2.kmz` file from FEMA here:
https://hazards.fema.gov/femaportal/wps/portal/NFHLWMSkmzdownload

My goal is to take that file and convert it to a format that I can feed to MapBox or otherwise use to populate a PostGIS database. My preferred format is GeoJSON.

I found the following code on the StackExchange network, but it doesn't seem to work.

```
import gdal

srcDS = gdal.OpenEx('./FEMA_NFHL_v3.2.kmz')
ds = gdal.VectorTranslate('output.json', srcDS, format='GeoJSON')
```

The code above produces this error:

```
$ python scratch.py
Warning 1: The output driver does not natively support DateTime type for field timestamp. Misconversion can happen. -mapFieldType can be used to control field type conversion.
Warning 1: The output driver does not natively support DateTime type for field begin. Misconversion can happen. -mapFieldType can be used to control field type conversion.
Warning 1: The output driver does not natively support DateTime type for field end. Misconversion can happen. -mapFieldType can be used to control field type conversion.
ERROR 1: Layer 'NFHL' does not already exist in the output dataset, and cannot be created by the output driver.
ERROR 1: Terminating translation prematurely after failed
translation of layer NFHL (use -skipfailures to skip errors)
```

I unzipped the kmz file, and have the following:

```
$ tree FEMA_NFHL_v3.2
FEMA_NFHL_v3.2
├── doc.kml
└── files
    ├── FEMA_Logo.png
    ├── GenStruct_item.gif
    ├── LOMA_item.gif
    ├── Levee_item.gif
    ├── LiMWA_item.gif
    ├── NFHL_Legend.png
    ├── NFHL_Quick_Start_Instructions.png
    └── RivMrk_item.gif

1 directory, 9 files
```

It looks like the only file worth considering that contains any data is `doc.kml`. Inspecting `doc.kml`, I see there's some code referencing a FEMA webservice. Further, opening `FEMA NFHL v3.2 kmz` in Google Earth, I see that it is, indeed, making web service calls.

Is there a way to programatically, using Python, have the .kmz file make the webservice calls and then generate a GeoJSON file?

Comment: "This or that" questions are effectively two questions, which violates our One question per Question policy. Please choose whether you want JSON or shapefile output; you can ask for the other in a later question, if necessary.

Comment: I updated the question limiting it to GeoJSON, though a shapefile would also do.

Comment: No you can't.  WMS services return styled map images.  According to the FEMA site, you can download the actual data - "Using the “Search All Products” on the [MSC](https://msc.fema.gov/), you can download the NFHL data for a County or State in shapefile format."  See also https://www.fema.gov/media-library-data/1506543141582-6cba7e3537090d435ae283605cf7570c/FEMA_Hazard_Products_Direct_Download.pdf